# How to convert a binary string to array?

Tags: php

For example I have an integer

`$mask = 210;`

which in binary is

`$binary = decbin($mask); // "11010010"`

Now I want to convert this ($mask or $binary) to an array with the indexes which is true:

`$expected = [2, 5, 7, 8];`

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: So, show us what have you tried.

Comment: what is your logic for $expected = [2, 5, 7, 8];

Comment: Split `$binary` to an array, push a 0 to give yourself offsets from 1 rather than from zero, reverse it, filter to remove falsey values, and get the keys

Comment: @u_mulder only str_split came to my mind and then use foreach to loop the chars array to push the indexes to an new array if the value is "1", but I guess this would not be efficient, comparing to bitwise operations...

Comment: @Phoenix I assume you are trying to create a bitmask for permission storage. If that's not the case, please update the question with your intended goal and I'll vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this manually:

```
$expected = array();

$mask = 210;
$binary = strrev(decbin($mask)); // strrev reverts the string

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($binary); $i++)
{
    if ($binary[$i] === '1') $expected[] = ($i + 1);
}
```

Working [IDEOne demo](http://ideone.com/S9fOjf).

**Important note:** bits are usually being numerated from zero. So, the correct answer would be "1 4 6 7". Change `($i + 1)` to `$i` in order to achieve this result.

Answer (score 0):

Split $binary to an array, push a 0 to give yourself offsets from 1 rather than from zero, reverse it, filter to remove falsey values, and get the keys

```
$mask = 210;
$binary = decbin($mask); // "11010010"

$tmp = str_split($binary, 1);
$tmp[] = 0;
$expected = array_keys(
    array_filter(
        array_reverse($tmp)
    )
);

var_dump($expected);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/JEQcG)